# File delete versus overwrite and link at /proc/pid/fd

Tags: linux, files, open-files, proc

It is well known that UNIX systems won't actually delete a file on disk while the file is in use. So if a file is being accessed by process 1 and process 2 deletes the file using rm,  process 1 continues to see the file; additionally the file descriptor link at /proc/(process 1 id)/fd reports the original contents of the deleted file.

However, if process 2 overwrites the file as opposed to deleting it (say with echo "abracadabra" > file.txt), the file descriptor link at /proc/(process 1 id)/fd reports the overwriting material("abracadabra"), while process 1 is still able to access the original contents of the file.
Why this difference?

[Edit]The snippet below is in response to Jim Paris

```
>uname -a
Linux ravoori-netbook 3.2.0-32-generic-pae #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:54:23 UT
C 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
>echo original > /tmp/foo
>tail -0f /tmp/foo &
[2] 6144
>rm /tmp/foo
>cat /proc/6144/fd/3
original
>echo abracadabra > /tmp/foo
>cat /proc/6144/fd/3
original
```

Comment: Each directory entry is a hard link to the file.  A single file can have entries in multiple directories (i.e. multiple hard links).  The kernel will reclaim the disk blocks once the *last* link to the file is gone.  Until then, unlinking merely removes the directory entry - it does nothing to the file contents.

Comment: @jw013, thanks. With respect to the overwrite scenario described above, understood that the reading process continues to see the original file contents but why does the descriptor under /proc/<<process ID>>/fd point to the new contents? This is different than the delete scenario where /proc/<<process ID>>/fd clearly points to original file

Comment: Process 1 obtains fd to a file.  Process 2 obtains fd to the same file.  Both processes see the same contents.  This is natural and expected behavior.  Whatever one process writes the other can see because both have the *same* file open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If process 1 has already started reading the file before process 2 overwrites it, then it will have some part of the contents stored in the `stdio` buffer. Once it crosses the buffer-size boundary it will be forced to go to the kernel, and then it will find the new overwritten contents.

Answer (score 2):

> However, if process 2 overwrites the file as opposed to deleting it
>   (say with echo "abracadabra" > file.txt), the file descriptor link at
>   /proc/(process 1 id)/fd reports the overwriting
>   material("abracadabra"), while process 1 is still able to access the
>   original contents original le.

I disagree:

```
$ echo original > /tmp/foo
$ tail -0f /tmp/foo &
[1] 20591
$ rm /tmp/foo
$ cat /proc/20591/fd/3
original
$ echo abracadabra > /tmp/foo
$ cat /proc/20591/fd/3
original
```

The `fd` link still shows the original contents, contrary to what you claimed.
This is with Linux 3.5.  Are you seeing something different?

Comment: I see different behaviour. Please refer snippet added to original question.

Comment: Actually, your snippet above appears to prove my point. The abracadabra displayed by the final cat is different than the original content. However, this same procedure when run on my setup provides results that are contrary to my original point. The original question pertained to a production situation involving processes under different sessions slowly looping through large files therefore the stdio buffering referenced by aecolley might have something to do with it.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I hand edited that transcript and messed up the most important part!  I ran the commands again and they match your output; I'll fix the snippet.